# Drill down from chart Legend

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportbuilder, reportbuilder3.0

I'm building report using SSRS 2008 (Report builder 3.0)

I'm afraid I know the answer but still wondering if there is a way to link to Drill down report from the Legend area ? I know I can do it from the data labels.

[image]

Did anyone succeeded to crate some workarounds?

Comment: Very limited on the legend see this discussion http://support2.dundas.com/forum/tm.aspx?m=16388&mpage=1&key=&#16388

Comment: Good question and a nice improvement for microsoft to jump on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't claim this as my own but as soon as I read it I felt silly myself. ;)

Basically use a tablix next to your chart.

[SSRS (Reporting Services) Separate Legend (as Tablix) From Chart or Graph with Drilldown Links](http://roberthydell.blogspot.com.au/2011/07/ssrs-reporting-services-separate-legend.html)

Comment: Stupid me :) this is a simple solution for such a huge problem with the ssrs reports. Thanks @glh this is a good one.